# What is a sliding-window convolutional neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

In the abstract of "U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical
Image Segmentation", the authors mention a sliding-window convolutional neural network. I've found several other articles mentioning this but no clean definition of it. How is it different from regular convolutional networks/what does the term mean?

Answer (score 1):

Sliding window in this context is regarding what is given as input to the CNN. It is a sliding window of the input image. I have seen it being used in medical domain where the images are too large to fit into a network and reshaping them into smaller sizes doesn't help. So, a sliding window is done on the bigger image and the sliding window is fed into CNN for achieving whatever task you are trying to achieve.